# Adding active class to anchor tags

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I've been trying to add a `.active` class to the current link and I know it's been asked here before, but, none of the answers seems to match my need exactly.

It's a Vue component. I don't want to add vue-router. I want to add the active class dynamically to whichever link is clicked.

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, $index) in items" :key="$index" >
        <a :href="item.link">{{ item.name }}</a>     //how do I dynamically add the active class here?
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Navbar",
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      default: null,
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style>
 ul li .active {
   background-color: red;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
</style>
```

The list of links:

```
const items = [
  {
    name: "Home",
    link: "#home",
  },
  { 
    name: "About", 
    link: "#about" 
  },
  {
    name: "Contacts",
    link: "#contact",
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `hashchange` event and Vue's [class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes):

```
<template>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(item, $index) in items" :key="$index">
                <a :href="item.link" :class="{ active: hash === item.link }">{{ item.name }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Navbar',

    props: {
        items: {
            type: Array,
            default: null,
        },
    },

    data() {
        return {
            hash: window.location.hash,
        };
    },

    created() {
        window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => {
            this.hash = window.location.hash;
        });
    },
};
</script>

<style>
ul li .active {
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

---

Another solution is to use a `click` event and `setTimeout`.

Using `setTimeout` without a delay will simply [push the evaluation to the back of the queue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), meaning it waits for the URL to update **before** reading it. Without this, the method will always be one step behind.

Here's an example:

```
<template>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(item, $index) in items" :key="$index">
                <a
                    @click="setUrlSection(item.section)"
                    :href="item.link"
                    :class="{ active: urlSection === item.link }"
                    >{{ item.name }}</a
                >
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Navbar',

    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                {
                    name: 'Home',
                    link: '#home',
                    section: 'hash',
                },
                {
                    name: 'About',
                    link: '/about',
                    section: 'pathname',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Contacts',
                    link: '#contact',
                    section: 'hash',
                },
            ],
            urlSection: window.location.hash || window.location.pathname,
        };
    },

    methods: {
        setUrlSection(section) {
            setTimeout(() => (this.urlSection = window.location[section]));
        },
    },
};
</script>

<style>
ul li .active {
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

Keep in mind, you have to add a `section` property to each item so it knows which `window.location` property to read.

Comment: just a quick question, will it work for `/home, /about` kind of links too? or is it just with `#`

Comment: what if I want for both `/ and #`. is there a collective solution for both?

Comment: yeah it's working for the # one and since I dont have vue router for now so I can't test it with the '/'. also why did you use same section name for home and contacts but different for about. it doesn't matter right? i can set it to anything?

Comment: I tested it with vue-router so it should work fine. The section properties are just to demonstrate how you'd use it with a mix of both hash and path, so, you can use it with anything.

Comment: The only flaw in this is if you have a mix of hash and path in a link, the hash would be evaluated on page-load before the path. It really depends on your use-case how you might handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VueJs `:class`

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, $index) in items" :key="$index" >
        <a :href="item.link" :class="{'active': current_page_name == item.name }">{{ item.name }}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    current_page_name() {
        return this.$route.name;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

If you do not want to use `vue-router` you'll have to write more code.
Here is example

```
<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      url: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    current_page_name() {

      if(this.url){
        var URL = this.url;
        var arr=URL.split('/');
        var route_name = arr[1]; // i think zero is the domain, then 1 is the page name,
        return route_name;
      }

      return '';
    }
  },

  mounted(){
    this.url = window.location.href;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: it says `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. coming from the item.name in the `:class`

Comment: Make sure there is a prop or variable called items.

Comment: it's there for sure. i checked

Comment: it's the full erro `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at VueComponent.current_page_name `

Comment: Sorry, i haven't tested the code. i just wrote it from my mind. anyway, change ```this.$route.name``` to ```this.$router.currentRoute```

Comment: I dont have vue router in my project though. can it be the reason for this error? as im still getting `Cannot read property 'currentRoute' of undefined` error

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to use Vue-Router?

If `items` are returned from an API, item is undefined until the Promise has returned. Try `item.name !== undefined && current_page_name === item.name`?

Comment: oh!. Ofcourse. you said you do not want to use ```vue-router```

Comment: @Excalibaard for now I'm just using static content to test it and it isn't working. not getting the links from api for now

Comment: @chawila so I don't need vue-router for this to work? it's still not working tho :(

Comment: @deadbeforesunlight you need ```vue-router```, let me update my answer to something that does not need ```vue-router```

Comment: vue-router is by far the easiest, and is necessary if you want to use `this.$route.name`. You can do it without vue-router, by getting the current URL using `window.location.href` and manually stripping the link for something that matches your items.

Comment: I tried using window.location.pathname. but the links aren't getting highlighted for some reason @Excalibaard

Comment: I don't know what you tried to use to match the pathname with the arbitrarily defined items, so if you could update your question with that code it'd be helpful.

Comment: @deadbeforesunlight you could have saved yourself a lot of time by just using the ```vue-router```, anyway i have updated my answer.

Comment: did you mean `return route_name` in the last line?

Comment: Pretty sure he did

Comment: @deadbeforesunlight yes, i have fixed the error.

Comment: @chawila I'm testing in storybook, and my storybook looks something like this `http://localhost:8080/iframe.html?id=navbar--navbar&viewMode=story#home` so it's still not highlighting the current link. yes I did change to `.split('#')` to match my use case but it's not highlighting the background color for some reason

Comment: I do not understand why you'll want to use ```#``` to update the page url and still not want to use ```vue-router```, it's like you want to build your own ```vue-router```

Comment: cause it's a ui library component. dont want to install any addons @chawila